# Loop with socket.io terminates at the beginning

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, socket.io

I'm building this function for upload to the server small tile images.
The client builds the **tileBuffer** and then calls the *fireTiles* function.
Here I would like to build a loop based on the **tileBuffer.length**. The server will handle the control. So, i emit *StartAddTiles* and I immediately called back from the server with the *AnotherTile* event. The debugger shows me I've been called by the server and I see the code going into the *socket.on('AnotherTile'...* sentence.

The problem is that when the code reaches the **AddTile** emit function, it stops there and nothing happens. The server does not receive the request and the loop is terminated there.

Where is the error in my code?

```
 function fireTiles (tileBuffer, mapSelected) {

        var tiles =   tileBuffer.length;
        var tBx = 0;

        try
        {
            var socket = io.connect('http://myweb:8080/');

            socket.emit('StartAddTiles', tiles, mapSelected);   
            socket.on('AnotherTile', function (tlN){
                if (tlN < tiles) {
                    var data = tileBuffer[tlN];  //uso tlN per far comandare il server
                    tBx++; // debug purpose
                    socket.emit('AddTile', mapSelected, data, tBx);
                } else {
                // something went wrong
                    alert('Error calculating tiles');
                    return;
                }
            });
        }
        catch(err)
        {
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = err.message;
        }


    }
```

Here is the server side:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(client) {
  console.log('Connecting....');
// controls are limited, this is just a beginning

  // Initiate loop
  client.on('StartAddTiles', function(tiles, mapSelected) {
    var mapId = mapSelected;
    mapLoading[mapId] = {  //Create a new Entry in The mapLoading Variable
    tilesToLoad : tiles,
    tilesLoaded : 0
    }
     console.log('Start loading '+mapLoading[mapId].tilesToLoad+' tiles.');
    // Ask for the first tile
    client.emit('AnotherTile', mapLoading[mapId].tilesLoaded);
      //

  });

  // client add new Tile/Tiles
  client.on('addTile', function(mapSelected, data, tBx) {
    var mapId = mapSelected;
    mapLoading[mapId].tilesLoaded = ++1;
    console.log('Adding tile '+mapLoading[mapId].tilesLoaded+' of '+mapLoading[mapId].tilesToLoad+' tBx '+tBx);

    // insert Tile
    db_manager.add_tiles(tileBuffer, function(result) {

        if (mapLoading[mapId].tilesLoaded == mapLoading[mapId].tilesToLoad) {  // full map loaded
        mapLoading[mapId] = "";  //reset the buffer
        client.emit('TilesOk', mapLoading[mapId].tilesLoaded);
        } else {
        console.log('requesting tile num: '+mapLoading[mapId].tilesLoaded);
        client.emit('AnotherTile', mapLoading[mapId].tilesLoaded);
        }
      //

    });
  });
```

Comment: can you show the server side code too?

Comment: I'm feel very stupid ;-) Thanks a lot

Comment: nah, you shouldn't be. This stuff just happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event names are case sensitive, you should probably use `AddTile` instead of `addTile` on the server side too.